# How to disable images in react native's webview?

Tags: java, android, react-native, webview, bridge

I would like to know how you'd go about disabling images in react native's webview or to access the `getSettings()` method on android's webview.

Comment: brother can you please tell what you have tried so far? any code snippet! please add!

Comment: you can use inject javaScript in webView which should take the incoming html page and disable all the image urls coming thorough it!

Comment: please tell more or share some code

Comment: I've tried coding it out but I don't know java programming at the moment and I find it very difficult to follow the documentation where native code is concerned. I'm basically trying to bridge a custom android webview where image loading is disabled.